# Displaying quotes before and after text

Tags: css, quotes

I am struggling with lining up quotes before and after a paragraph, I have used the css psuedo classes content: open-quote; on before and after but for some odd reason the alignment is all over the place, I need the quote marks about four times the size of the paragraph to match the designs Ive been given, also the last line of text has a large gap, I have been toying with this all morning with no success, I have written a code pen to demo this, has anybody got any suggestions on how I might be able to make this work?

When increasing the font size on the psuedo elements the quote marks have additional height which seems to be causing issues, I have added borders to them to demonstrate this.

https://codepen.io/barrypoore/pen/EQgPzz

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>

p {
 font-size: 1.5em;
 line-height: 1.5em;
}

p:before {
 content: open-quote;
}

p:after {
 content: close-quote;
}

p:before,
p:after {
 display:inline;
 font-size: 6em;
 color: orange;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
 top: .25em;
 }
```

Comment: add `display: flex;` to `p`

Comment: or `display:table` to `p` and `display:table-cell` to pseudo element

Answer (score 13):

## Use Blockquotes

Don't use a `p` tag for quotes. You should use the [Blockquote](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_blockquote.asp) tag.

Then use before and after psudo classes.

I have updated your code pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OQRNKB#anon-login

```
blockquote {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

blockquote:before {
  content: open-quote;
}

blockquote:after {
  content: close-quote;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  color: orange;
  font-size: 4em;
  top: .2em;
  position: relative;
}
```